# List of RadioButtons on Android, Java

Tags: java, android

I need create a list of RadioButtons, but if I try to do it with ListView than I can select all radiobuttons simultaneously, but I need 1 selected radiobutton simultaneously. Therefore, I can try this code:

```
RadioGroup group=new RadioGroup(this);
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);

for (String item:mMusicData.keySet()) {
    RadioButton button=new RadioButton(this);
    button.setText(item);
    group.addView(button);
}

layout.addView(group);
```

But layout doesn't show all items, because layout is small. I need scrollbar or another mean for my task. Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your `ListView` to single mode. For this add `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` to layout that contains your `ListView`:

```
 <ListView ... android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

Comment: Does Android has a standart mean for creating listview of radiobuttons?

Comment: This is a standard way of creating it.